# pygame click_pos coordinates

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

Im using a piTFT and along with pygame. I was able to draw the elements on the screen using the desired coordinates.

Now I would like to make those elements clickable.

I found various example on the internet but I do not understand how it works. For example to draw a rectangle you need to specify the coordinates of the upper left hand corner. (screen.blit(login,(56,67)))

But for the click_pos I see:

```
if 270 <= click_pos[0] <= 320 and 10 <= click_pos[1] <=50:
        print "You pressed exit"
```

What are those 2 coordinates?

Can someone please explain me whats behind it so I can do my own code?

Comment: Can you link the example you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `click_pos[0]` and `click_pos[1]` represent the x and y position of the mouse when the user click.
guessing that in x your button border are [270-320] and in y [10-50]
So `270 <= click_pos[0] <= 320` and `10 <= click_pos[1] <=50` make sure that the x and y position of the mouse are in the limit of your button